# c++ Static member function in logging class

Tags: c++, function, static, member

For learning purposes, I am doing static class for logging.
I have function "startLog" which delete any file with same name and open file for writing.
And I have fuction "log" which print into file some text and it works. However when this function is called from "startLog", no writing to file is done.

**Expected result in log.log file:**
[INFO]   2022-07-29 20:04:07.?????? | log.cpp:34: void startLog (const std::string&) | Log opening ... log.log
[DEBUG]   2022-07-29 20:04:07.465570 | main.cpp:15: int main(int, char**) | TEST1 - START!
[DEBUG]   2022-07-29 20:04:08.547214 | main.cpp:22: int main(int, char**) | TEST1 - END!

**However after running it there is only this in log.log file:**
[DEBUG]   2022-07-29 20:04:07.465570 | main.cpp:15: int main(int, char**) | TEST1 - START!
[DEBUG]   2022-07-29 20:04:08.547214 | main.cpp:22: int main(int, char**) | TEST1 - END!

### main.cpp

```
#include "log.hpp"

#include <iostream>

int main(int, char*[])
{
    std::string logFile {"log.log"};
    Log::startLog (logFile);
    Log::startLog ("log1.txt");
    int testCycles {100'000};


    Log::log ("TEST1 - START!", Log::DEBUG, logFile);

    for (int i = 0; i < testCycles; ++i)
    {
        Log::log("TEST" + std::to_string(i), Log::INFO, "log1.txt");
    }

    Log::log ("TEST1 - END!", Log::DEBUG, logFile);



    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

### log.hpp

```
#ifndef LOG_HPP
#define LOG_HPP

#include <fstream>
#include <source_location>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

class Log
{
    public:
        enum
        {
            INFO,
            DEBUG,
            WARNING,
            ERROR,
            FATAL,
        };

        static void log                             (std::string_view errorMsg, int severity = Log::INFO, const std::string& logFile = s_logFile,
                                                                const std::source_location location = std::source_location::current());
        static void startLog                        (const std::string& logFile = "log.log");
        static std::string getLogFile               (){return s_logFile;};
        static void setLogLevel                     (int logLevel);

    private:
        static inline std::string                   s_logFile;
        static inline std::fstream                  s_outf {s_logFile, std::ios::app};
        static inline std::string                   s_logMsg [] = {"[INFO]", "[DEBUG]", "[WARNING]","[ERROR]", "[FATAL]"};
        static inline int                           s_logLevel = Log::INFO;
        Log                                         (){};


};

#endif // LOG_HPP_INCLUDED
```

### log.cpp

```
#include "log.hpp"
#include "utilities.hpp"

#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string_view>

void Log::log                               (std::string_view errorMsg, int severity, const std::string& logFile, const std::source_location location)
{
    if (severity < Log::INFO)               severity = Log::INFO;
    else if (severity > Log::FATAL)         severity = Log::FATAL;
    if (severity < s_logLevel)              return;
    if (logFile != s_logFile)
    {
        s_outf.close();
        s_outf.open (logFile, std::ios::app);
        s_logFile = std::move (logFile);
    }
    s_outf
        << std::left << std::setw(10) << s_logMsg[severity]
        << Util::getTimeMillisec() << " | "
        << std::filesystem::path(location.file_name()).filename().string() << ":" << location.line() << ": " << location.function_name() << " | "
        << errorMsg <<'\n';

    // should be optimized in C++23 using location.resource_file to get filename instead of using std::filesystem

}

void Log::startLog                          (const std::string& logFile)
{
    s_logFile = logFile;
    remove (s_logFile.c_str());
    log ("Log opening ... " + s_logFile);
}

void Log::setLogLevel                       (int logLevel)
{
    if (logLevel < 0)                       s_logLevel = 0;
    else if (logLevel > Log::FATAL)         s_logLevel = Log::FATAL;
    else                                    s_logLevel = logLevel;
}
```

note: there is utilities.hpp and utilities.cpp to get formatting time point and it works fine, so I do not included code here.

Comment: It looks like `startLog` doesn't actually open `s_outf` itself. And then once you get to the `log` statement inside `startLog`, `s_logFile == logFile` is `true` and so that doesn't try to open `s_outf` either.

Comment: But if I call directly    Log::log ("TEST1 - START!", Log::DEBUG, logFile); from main, it works. As s_outf is static std::fstream it should remain opened till close (as it works with directly calling loop in main and it correctly print 100,000 times into "log1.txt" or am I wrong?

Comment: Just go through your code very carefully, paying particular attention to what exactly the value of `s_logFile` is at each step and when, exactly, `s_outf` is opened. It _doesn't_ get opened in a `startLog` call. It only gets opened when you call `log` with a value for `logFile` that doesn't match the current value of `s_logFile`, which does end up happening because you have both `"log.log"` and `"log1.txt"`.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear, s_logFile should be initialized with some default value. I used static as I do not want to initialized object for logging and ability to have log class easily accesible elsewhere.

Comment: A default value for `s_logFile` might be appropriate, but it's not sufficient to address this. You still need to make sure that `startLog` actually opens or reopens `s_outf` with the appropriate file path. Your code still won't work if all you do is provide a default value for `s_logFile`.

Comment: Yes, I needed to add closing file before deleting targetted file and than reopening file in startLog function. It works now. I will think tommorow if it can be done better. I really appretiate your help, especially as I am just hobbiest programmer - it is not my job.

Answer (score 1):

`Log::startLog` can never result in the log file being opened since the `s_logFile` is set to the default parameter of the `log` call. There's no file opened initially either, since passing the empty string to the constructor of `std::fstream` does not result in the file being opened.

You probably want something like

```
class Log
{
...
    static inline std::string                   s_logFile; // empty initially; will result in opening the file stream the first time a file name is passed to log
    static inline std::fstream                  s_outf; // not opened initially as before (opening file "" fails)
...
};
```

```
void Log::startLog(const std::string& logFile)
{
    remove(s_logFile.c_str());
    log("Log opening ... " + s_logFile, Log::INFO, logFile);
}
```

---

Furthermore you should listen to your compiler warnings:

In

```
s_logFile = std::move(logFile);
```

you're moving a const lvalue reference. You should simply use the copy assignment operator instead.

Comment: Fabian, thanks for advice relating to std::move, you are right. And your solution is even nicer than adding default value to static s_logFile.

Answer (score -1):

Does your Code even compile?
You have a weird typo in the initialization of testCycles in your Main function. Probably the loop is called zero times.
Also static means, that your member variable s_logFile is global. You call it twice with two different paramters. I dont think it will do, what you intended.

Last: Google about ifstream/ofstream. If you use it properly, you don't need to call open/close.

Comment: What typo in the initialization of `testCycles`? If you mean the apostrophe, that's been a [valid digit separator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) since C++14.

Comment: Beyond that, this simply isn't an answer. Requests for clarification and additional information are comments. This speculates but does not definitely diagnose what's wrong, and it doesn't even attempt to offer a solution.

Comment: It compiles without problems. The loop is for 100,000 times (100'000)

Comment: As statet in my answer.  s_logFile should not be static.

Comment: Actuall, its wrong, that i did not mention a solution! The core problems are the misuse of static variables for everything and the wrong usage of fstream. If you use fstream, you should very rarely have the need to call open/close. Do I need to write his homework?

Comment: "Just google it yourself and write it correctly" may be good advice, but it's not an answer.

Comment: sveberk. I undestand that static member functions are global and as singleton should not be used. However I have found nowhere how to solve this. I found everywhere that they are bad and reasons for that. But I have not found anywhere how to do it properly if you need global access. If I make s_logFile not static it means objects need to be initialized and every part of the programs need to track this object or create own object. Static member function eliminates this complication.

Comment: You have logFile as parameter in your Log::log function. If the caller/user of Log::log has to provide the file name for the log file, why do you have it also as static member s_logFile in your class? On the other hand, if you want to log always into the same file, why you provide the filename in your log::log function? Key word: "Single source of truth".